# Reorder box and whiskers plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following minimal example code in R:

```
data.time = c(1, 4, 8, 9, 2, 4, 1)  
data.difficulty = c("hard", "simple", "simple", "hard", "simple", "simple", "hard")  
library(lattice)  
bwplot(data.time ~ data.difficulty, xlab="Difficulty", ylab="Time")
```

If you graph it, you can see "hard" is on the left and "simple" is on the right.  I want that reversed.  Is there a way to do this without transforming or modifying my original data?  I don't want to change it because the data is used later on for other graphs and analysis.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks all, I was able to use relevel to successfully switch that ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the relevel function to order the reference to to be "simple".  I had to convert the data.difficulty to factor first because it's character.

```
data.difficulty<-relevel(as.factor(data.difficulty), ref="simple")
bwplot(data.time ~ data.difficulty, xlab="Difficulty", ylab="Time")
```

Answer (score 3):

Following the other answers: this breaks your rules a little bit by organizing the data as a data frame (so that we can `transform` it on the fly for `bwplot`), but if you can stand it, it's probably a better way to organize your analyses in general ... lots of things in R (e.g. model prediction) get easier when variables from the same set are packed into data frames rather than lying around as individual objects in the workspace.  The rest of your commands get easier to read, too, as long as you use `data=` arguments appropriately.

```
data.time = c(1, 4, 8, 9, 2, 4, 1)  
data.difficulty = c("hard", "simple", "simple", "hard", 
                  "simple", "simple", "hard")  
mydata <- data.frame(time=data.time,difficulty=data.difficulty)
library(lattice)  
bwplot(time ~ difficulty, xlab="Difficulty", ylab="Time",
   data = transform(mydata,
       difficulty=relevel(difficulty,"simple")))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if converting the difficulty vector to a factor violates your constraint about not changing the data. Ever other function will most likely treat this on the same basis as the original character vector.

```
dfrm <- data.frame(time=data.time, difficulty=data.difficulty) 
 dfrm$difficulty <- factor(dfrm$difficulty, levels=c("simple", "hard") )
 bwplot(time ~ difficulty, data=dfrm, xlab="Difficulty", ylab="Time")
```